# Meaning of the "マンボスチン"

Tags: meaning

I wonder what she says

Context (from video [パズルでショーブヨ！ウータマちゃん ending](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04PD2Z_XrSY))

> クリアしたわね！アッパレよ、アナタ！ウータマ、ムーチョ・ラブよ
>
> じつはアタシ、テンシだったんだけど、いま、なぜかアイドルやってるの。アイドルのみちはケモノみちよ！！
>
> ウータマをみつけたら、あっついキスをおねがいね！
>
> アタシのマンボスチン！

If try to translate with DeepL by replacing マンボスチン with まんぼす- "my favourite person". Maybe a typo, can be a corruption or contraction.

Comment: マン**ホ**スチン or マン**ボ**スチン? I guess one of them is a typo. Either way I have no idea what it means.

Comment: Ending "チン" also just like she saying in childish style, but there usually "s" or "sh" sounds change to "ch" おいしい -> おいちい

Comment: I've fixed some typos. If they're wrong, please revert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about this character, but as far as I can tell from my search, there is no indication that マンボスチン was ever used even as slang. I think it's most likely that it's just a made-up word made by combining マンゴスチン (mangosteen) and マンボ (mambo), with no particular meaning other than that it has a "tropical" ring. That ムーチョ should be also for the same purpose.